# How to pass specific value to the converter parameter?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How I send an static value inside ConverterParameter such as a number?

```
<Label Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}" Text="{Binding Information, Converter={StaticResource CutStringConverter}, ConverterParameter={100}}" />
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably need to include the type then. So either do it inline like this: `ConverterParameter={x:Int32 100}`.

Or write it more verbose:

```
<Label>
     <Label.Text>
         <Binding Path="Information" Converter="{StaticResource CutStringConverter}">
             <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                 <x:Int32>100</x:Int32>
             </Binding.ConverterParameter>
        </Binding>
    </Label.Text>
</Label>
```

Or, to be complete, add a static resource to your page (or whatever the container is), like:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <x:Int32 x:Key="IntHundred">100</x:Int32>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

And reference that: `ConverterParameter={StaticResource IntHundred}`

Comment: ConverterParameter={StaticResource Somehthing} not working