# hide rows in a data cell when switching a toggle

Tags: listview, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

Here is my xaml template file:

```
    <Switch  IsToggled="{Binding ShowSubItems}" Grid.Row = "0" Grid.Column = "1" HorizontalOptions = "Start" Margin = "10,8,8,0"></Switch>
```

followed by:

```
      <ListView x:Name="lvItemSigns" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="Default" SeparatorColor="Gray" Margin =" 8">
```

Im binding data cell to this list as follows:

```
                lvItemSigns.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(DataCell));

        class DataCell : ViewCell{
public DataCell()
        {
            var grid = new Grid();
            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height =  GridLength.Auto});
            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });

            label = new Label();
            label.TextColor = Color.Black;
            label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "SubItemCode");
            label.Margin = 4;
            grid.Children.Add(label, 1, 3);

            label = new Label();
            label.TextColor = Color.Black;
            label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "SubItemDescription");
            label.Margin = 4;

            label.SetBinding(Label.IsVisibleProperty, new Binding("SubItemDescription", BindingMode.Default, new BooleanConverter()));

            grid.Children.Add(label, 1, 4);
}
```

How to hide this two labels from each datacell of the list when the toggle is switched.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When setting the IsVisibleProperty, the binding property shouldn't be 'ShowSubItems'?

code will be,

```
label.SetBinding(Label.IsVisibleProperty, new Binding("ShowSubItems", BindingMode.Default, new BooleanConverter()));
```

also, Make sure you have notifying the property changed in the 'ShowSubItems' property.like,

```
 private bool showSubItems;
    public bool ShowSubItems
    {
        get { return showSubItems; }
        set { showSubItems = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
```

also the converter code should be,

```
public class BooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType != typeof(bool))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a boolean");

        return !(bool)value;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Optional: throw new NotSupportedException();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, as I'm already using IsVisible property in one of the label setbinding ("SubItemDescription"), how to use one more bool value ("ShowSubItems") for visible property

Comment: you are binding SubItemDescription for both Text and Isvisible property.. I hope SubItemDescription is a string property that is used for display the sub item description. ShowSubItems is the bool property that you are using in Switch control for setting label's visibility. So you have to use the same ShowSubItems in the IsVisible property of the label.

Comment: I was using SubItemDescription for visible property because I need to show that row only if it has text in it. So I have to use SubItemDescription and also ShowSubItems(property for switch) as visible property.

Comment: SubItemDescription - Is it string or bool?

Comment: its a string, but im using booleanConverter here (            label.SetBinding(Label.IsVisibleProperty, new Binding("SubItemDescription", BindingMode.Default, new BooleanConverter()));
) which returns true if there is a text in it

Comment: Ok. Let me rephrase your requirement. Toggling the switch should show and hide the label description. When toggled OFF label should be hidden. When toggled ON and if description text has values then show the description label otherwise description label should be hidden. Isn't it?

Comment: Exactly. Sorry if i confused you before.

Comment: No issues.. This scenario, either you can handle by using another bool parameter, in which when setting the value, you can check both ShowSubItems is true and SubItemDescription has data. Another way is passing parameter in the converter and handle the samething there. For passing parameter in converter refer the below links.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45391156/how-to-pass-specific-value-to-the-converter-parameter

Comment: hi.. i Have small doubt regarding this. Can we bind visible property of stack layout to a toggle event. It's not working for me. Thanks